# Check an unknown type of argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, numpy-ndarray, nonetype

I'm passing an argument(lets say the variable 'a') to a function, and this variable can either equal None or be a np.array.

```py
# Option 1
a = None

# Option 2
a = np.array(range(0,10))
```

Depending on what a equals, I want to do different things.

This is what I did:

```py
if a == None:
     do this
else:
     do that
```

The problem with this is that a np.array cant equal None and I get the following message:
"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

However, if I use a.any() or a.all() and a = None, a different error pops up because None doesn't have the attribute 'any' or 'all'.

How can I fix this in a nice way?

I tried the following but it seems that there must be a better way than duplicating code, or am I wrong?

```py
try:
     if a == None:
          do this
     else:
          do that
except:
     if a.any() == None:
          do this
     else:
          do that
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `is` instead of `==`:

```
if a is None:
     do this
else:
     do that
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if isinstance(a, np.ndarray):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

or

```
if type(a) is np.ndarray:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

or

```
if a is None:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

They all will work.